# Custom serialization/deserialization methods in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Is it possible to supply your own methods for serializing and deserializing a type for protobuf-net to use in its' Serializer.Serialize() and Serializer.Deserialize() methods?

i.e. Write my own code using ProtoWriter and ProtoReader, instead of marking up the class with serialization attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mention of `ProtoReader` / `ProtoWriter` means this is a "v2" question, in which case you **don't** have to use the attributes *at all* - you can define the model at runtime via `TypeModel`. Re the question of custom serializers - at the moment, not exactly - but I expect I'll add an interface for this before long. The only problem is that the *caller* is then responsible You *might* also want to look at the experimental `DataTable` serializer, which does something similar.

There are some technical considerations too, though; in particular inheritance; the obvious pattern would be for your class to implement an interface, but this means that once the object is created it is too late to create a subclass. Unless the type that implements the interface *isn't* the entity itself, but a *separate* type that juts handles serialization/deserialization...